# How do I open the MDN Reference link using keyboard shortcuts in Vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

When I write code inside Vscode in a HTML, CSS or JavaScript file, Vscode intelisense opens a popup and there is a link to `MDN reference`. How can I open this link with a keyboard shortcut?

[image: you can see that link in this pic]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press `Ctrl + Shift + P` to see all the commands. Search for `Show Definition Preview Hover`, press `Enter` to focus this hover, then press `Tab` to focus the link and finally press `Enter` to open this link.